# How To Correctly Handle Success/Error with True-Myth

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, asynchronous

I’ve been trying out [true-myth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/true-myth) to wrap http responses, but I think I’m missing something because I am ending up with the inverted pyramid for subsequent requests. Something like:

```js
const authRes = await verifyAuth(req)
if (authRes.isOk) {
  const id = authRes.value.id
  const roleRes = await getRole(id)
  if (roleRes.isOk) {
    const accessRes = await canAccess(roleRes.value, req.docId)
      if (accessRes.isOk) {
        // Etc
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a contrived example, but how can I avoid this pyramid of doom?

Also, if any of these error, the `error` propery isn’t clear to typescript without an additional isErr check, ie

```js
const authRes = await verifyAuth(req)
if (authRes.isOk) {
  return true
} else {
  // ts error with or without else
  return { 
    status: 401,
    // red typescript squiggly under error saying it isn’t a property on authRes
    error: authRes.error 
  }
}
if (authRes.isErr) {
  return { 
   status: 401,
   // must wrap with isErr check before accessing error property, which adds two lines for every http request I want to have a separate error for
   error: authRes.error 
  }
}
```

This isn’t real code so I’m just talking about concepts here. How can I avoid these two scenarios that seem like they’ll really inflate the size? Anyone used this library and have an idea about something obvious I’m missing or if I’m just misusing true-myth somehow?